# -fvisibility=hidden not passed by compiler for Debug builds

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, static-libraries, visibility

I am building a project in which I have enabled `GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN` and `GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN` because I am consuming static libraries that were pre-built with those flags on.

However, when I build my project for Debug `-fvisibility=hidden` is not included in the compiler flags, but it does get included when I build my project for Release.

Is there any other flag that I need to turn on to make this happen?

Answer (score 4):

This is old, but it it seems the conflict comes from the Enable Testability setting. If you turn that off, then -fvisibility=hidden will work properly. It seems that Enable Testability has higher precedence over GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN.

If you need that setting, you can always modify the settings on a configuration basis and mix and match (ie. Enable Testability is on and OTHER_CFLAGS containing -fvisibility=hidden)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an Xcode bug. I didn’t find any other solution that setting `OTHER_CFLAGS` explicitly (in debug build only, on the same level `GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN` is set) to override it:

```
OTHER_CFLAGS = "-fvisibility=hidden";
```