# Using Xcode to compile -fvisibility=hidden

Tags: xcode

Anyone knows how to use Xcode to compile with -fvisibility=hidden

I am new to Xcode, Some screenshot would be better.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please look into this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You really should use the Build Setting for Symbols Hidden by Default, but note that Enable Testability conflicts with this, in which case you want to do as Michael Dautermann indicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to your project's build settings in Xcode, use the search field to look for "Other C Flags" and then enter in "`-fvisibility=hidden`" like this:
[image: add visibility hidden flag]

More info can be seen in this [very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861502/fvisibility-hidden-not-passed-by-compiler-for-debug-builds).